# How to add namespace to XML elements

Tags: c#, xml

How can I create  XML element as below with C# by adding namespace information

```
<Booking bookingRefCode="ABC2123331" bookingAction="addOrUpdate" bookingComplete="true" xmlns="http://schemas.test.com/booking" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://schemas.test.com/booking http://schemas.test.com/Current/xsd/booking.xsd">
```

and this is my current code

```
            xw.WriteAttributeString("bookingRefCode", book.jobRefNo);
            xw.WriteAttributeString("bookingAction", "addOrUpdate");
            xw.WriteAttributeString("bookingComplete", "true");
```

so i add new attributes like this

```
xw.WriteAttributeString("xmlns",  "http://schemas.test.com/booking");
```

but it is given an error any idea about this ?

Comment: Just edited to tag C#...

Comment: I think it should be `xsi:schemaLocation`, not `xmlns:schemaLocation`

Answer (score 0):

`xmlns` is not a standard attribute, it is a special namespace declaration. You should not add them directly, just add elements/attributes using a namespace and the `xmlns` declarations are added automatically - e.g.:

```
xw.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "http://schemas.test.com/booking http://schemas.test.com/Current/xsd/booking.xsd");
```

adds the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute and at the same time creates a `xsmln:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration.